# How to use FOURCC formats in SlimDX?

Tags: surface, slimdx, fourcc

Looking through [the defined surface formats of SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/docs/#T_SlimDX_Direct3D9_Format), some seem to be missing. I'm interested in using the [**NV12** format](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php).

Since the formats are defined as an enum, I can't pass in a FOURCC format as [I would be able to using unmanaged code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172558.aspx#FOURCC_Formats).

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlimDX enums are defined as ints, so you can cast any int to it.

```
int nvformat = 12345; //Replace number by the fourcc
SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format fmt = (SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format)nvformat;
```

Comment: Ah ... I thought that would throw an exception, but it doesn't. Thanks!